# Compiling an Old C++ library

Tags: c++, abi

I am pretty new to C++ and am using gcc 7.5.0 compiler. I want to use the following  [Parallel Max Clique (PMC)](https://github.com/ryanrossi/pmc) library in my code. So I downloaded the whole and repo and added the folder to my current working directory (where my main.cpp i.e. the program in which I want to include the pmc library, is). After building the file I got the following error :

**"undefined reference to `pmc::pmc_graph::pmc_graph(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'|"**

Now, I know why this is happening, this is happening because the [PMC Library](https://github.com/ryanrossi/pmc) was written in an old compiler, and hence I am probably trying to link together object files that were compiled with different values for the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro. [check link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html). The solution is to ensure that my underlying libraries (i.e. [PMC library](https://github.com/ryanrossi/pmc)) and my current cpp code(i.e. main.cpp) are compiled with either ABI off. Google search says that I have to build the whole code with   **-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0**. How shall I do it?? I am very confused. Is there any tutorial as to how shall I do it. I am currently using VScode/CodeBlocks.

Thanks a lot in Advance.

Comment: Why not just rebuild the PMC library with the new compiler?

Comment: How to do that??

Comment: Download the source, run `make`...

Comment: I did that too. I get the following error "g++ -O3 -fPIC -o pmc pmc_driver.o pmc_utils.cpp pmc_graph.cpp pmc_clique_utils.cpp pmc_heu.cpp pmc_maxclique.cpp pmcx_maxclique.cpp pmcx_maxclique_basic.cpp pmc_cores.cpp  -fopenmp
pmc_utils.cpp: In function ‘bool fexists(const char*)’:
pmc_utils.cpp:26:12: error: cannot convert ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}’ to ‘bool’ in return
     return ifile;
            ^~~~~
Makefile:42: recipe for target 'pmc' failed
make: *** [pmc] Error 1
"

Comment: change `return ifile` to `return ifile.good()`, there should be no other problems.

Comment: OK, So i was able to make it successfully, but now how do I include the pmc library and use the pmc_graph(filename) constructor.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry but this is not a free interactive tutorial on using C++. Comments are here to clarify the question. If you have a question, please hit the "Ask a question" button.